# MySQL - Add column to temporary table with current column count

Tags: mysql, temporary

There is MySQL temporary table definition with a predefined structure:

```
create temporary table TempTableName as
  select tData.id as id,
         tData.name as name
         tData.someData as data,
from SomeTableName tData inner join ...
```

As a result temp table contains some count of a row with some data.

How It can be modified with additioanl column to store rowNumber ?
for example:

```
id    name    data    num
<id>  <name> <data>   1
<id>  <name> <data>   2
<id>  <name> <data>   3
```

So new num column should contain the current count row. How it can be modified to be added such counter ?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to add counter column then:

```
create temporary table TempTableName as
  select tData.id as id,
         tData.name as name
         tData.someData as data,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY tData.id) num
from SomeTableName tData inner join ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The AUTO_INCREMENT needs to be set with a primary key, so if this is o.k. for you, cou could add

```
ALTER TABLE `temporary` ADD `num` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ADD PRIMARY KEY (`num`);
```

Comment: is here a way to add such column at creation time?

Comment: yes you can first you can create the table after thet insert and select
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temporary(id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, your column names);
 INSERT INTO temporary(coulmn names) 
select  tData.id as id,
          tData.name as name
          tData.someData as data,
       from SomeTableName tData inner join ...;

Answer (score 0):

using variables

```
set @num  = 0;

select
   ...
   @num := @num + 1 as row_number,
```